# How to limit "diff -r" to a certain depth?

Tags: diff, directory-structure

How can I compare sub-directories in two directories down to a certain directory depth? Command `diff` doesn't have an option to specify depth, and `-r` option takes you all the way down to the files, which I want to avoid.

Basically, I would like to do this:

```
cd dir1
for d in */*/*; do test -d dir2/$d || echo $d; done
```

but more elegantly with a single command line and no loop.

Comment: Where does `diff` come into play in you example? Do you want the files at a certain depth, or up to that depth?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare directory content at a certain depth, in the above example two sub-directories deep.